# React nested component rendering issue

Tags: reactjs

here is my code

```
const Parent = (props) => <div> {props.children} </div>

it works: 

<Parent> <a href="/google">Click here </a> </Parent> 


This doesn't work 
<Parent> <Abutton /> </Parent> 

const Abutton = (props) => <a href="/google">Click here </a>
```

This is the issue

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
```

Comment: You are lacking a `/` for `<Abutton />`

Comment: edited the syntax

Comment: You have a typo in your code. `Abutton` is missing the `/` for the self-closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have mistakenly added `</props>` instead of `</div>` to close the tag.

```
const Parent = (props) => <div> {props.children} </div>
```

2. `<Abutton />` needs to be closed.

I've attached working snippet here.

```js
const Parent = (props) => <div> {props.children} </div>

const AButton = (props) => <a href="/link"> Link </a>


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent><AButton /></Parent>,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```